# Sharing image using facebook OpenGraphStories

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying Open Graph Stories in one of my app. FBShareDialog is used to preview the sharing. I can view the title and description in share dialog. But when I'm trying to share an image along with title and description, then share dialog will only show an image. It won't display the title and description.

Below is my code

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    self.photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
    self.photo.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.photo.userGenerated = YES;
}

- (IBAction)btnShare_Click:(id)sender {

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject alloc]init];
    [object setString:@"objName" forKey:@"og:type"];
    [object setString:@"Title" forKey:@"og:title"];
    [object setString:@"Testing Image sharing" forKey:@"og:description"];
    if (self.photo) {
        [object setPhoto:self.photo forKey:@"og:image"];
    }

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
    action.actionType = @"action";

    [action setObject:object forKey:@"objName"];

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
    content.action = action;
    content.previewPropertyName = @"app:objName";

    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:self];
}
```

In share dialog preview it will only show an image. It won't show title and description. If I post it, then post will contain title and description.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Ankita, which version of the SDK are you using? have you tried downloading the last Facebook SDK? When you install the SDK, you get an "Samples" project and there is a sample called "Share it" that does what you want. Why don't you check the example?

Comment: Where you able to solve this? Can you post the code on how you set "self.photo" ? Because og:image requires an array of FBSDKSharePhotoContent objects